# Extreme points of the convex set $S:=\{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : \|L\mathbf x\|_{*}\le 1\}.$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Is there any algorithm to obtain (approximate) extreme points (assuming the set of extreme points is non empty) of any convex set in a similar way like the well known simplex algorithm gets the extreme points in case of polytope?

The convex set that I am interested in  is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$
defined as

$$S:=\{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : \| L \mathbf x\|_{*} \le 1 \}$$

where $\|\cdot\|_*$ is norm in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ and $L$ is linear operator  mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Are there any characterizations that can help in building algorithm that return the extreme point of a set.

---

**Definition:** A point $z \in S$ is called the extreme point of the convex set $S$ if the set $S - \{z\}$ is convex.

Comment: What would such an algorithm return for a sphere?

Comment: I think this is much too general for a useful answer. If you [edit] the question to tell us just how the set is specified ("image of a projection" is not enough) and an example or two perhaps we can help.

Comment: @JohnHughes The set of extreme points is assumed to be non empty.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have narrowed down to a particular convex set.

Answer (score 1):

The vector unit $v$ in $n$-space that maps to the shortest possible vector in $2n$-space under $L$ is what you want to find. Then compute $w = Lv$, and let $s = \| w \|$. Then $\frac1s v$ is your desired vector.

How to find short vectors in the image? Compute the SVD of the matrix for $L$, and look at the singular vector corresponding to the smallest singular value.

You might want to try this for a few example maps from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^4$ to get a feel for how/why it works.

Here's an example for $n = 1$. Let
$$
L(x) = \pmatrix{3x \\ 4x} = \pmatrix{3 \\ 4} \pmatrix{x}
$$
The matrix is $M = \pmatrix{3 \\ 4}$.

The unit vectors in 1-space are $\pmatrix{\pm 1}$, and they map to $\pm \pmatrix{3 \\ 4}$. Those vectors have the same length (namely $5$), so each of them is the shortest possible, and could serve as $v$. But let's follow the instructions. We compute the SVD for $M$ (matlab interaction, somewhat cleaned up):

```
>> M = [3;4]    
M =    
     3
     4    
>> [u,d,v] = svd(M, 'econ')    
u =    
    0.6000
    0.8000    

d =    
     5    
v =    
     1
```

In short,
$$
\pmatrix{3\\4} = \pmatrix{3/5\\4/5} \pmatrix{5}\pmatrix{1}
$$
The smallest (indeed only) singular value is $5$; the corresponding right-eigenvector $v$ is $\pmatrix{1}$. $Lv$ is just $\pmatrix{3\\4}$, so $s = 5$. THen
$$
\frac{1}{s} v = \frac{1}{5}\pmatrix{1} = \pmatrix{1/5}
$$
is the largest vector in $\Bbb R^1$ that maps under $L$ to a unit vector in $\Bbb R^2$, as required. (Although $\pmatrix{-1/5}$ would also have worked.)

Comment: I believe you mean non zero singular values. 1)If $\|\cdot\|_*$ is not euclidean norm  $(L_2)$ would this answer be correct. Can we write some proof of the statement?

Comment: If $0$ is a singular value, any multiple of the corresponding singular vector will have length $0$ after transformation, so there's no extreme value: your convex set is unbounded. If the norm's not the Euclidean norm would it still be right? Almost certainly not. If it's a norm arising from an inner product, the answer can probably be adapted. If it's *not* from an inner product, then there no guarantee that the set you've defined in the domain is even convex. Can we write some proof? Sure. You should probably do that. It's not too hard, and it'll be instructive for you.